# how to move div1 when hovering div2

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I want to make "escaping" button, let me explain, when you try to click on button,itll move out..
i want to make button moving down, when you hover div1, moving up, when you hover div2 etc. ... this is what ive made : http://jsfiddle.net/6fsy8awj/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="cs-CZ"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
        <meta name="generator" content="Prace"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web8.css">
        <title>Rostik</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="button">
            <button name="button1" value="link">Tlačítko</button>  
        </div>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5"></div>
        <div id="div6"></div>
        <div id="div7"></div>
        <div id="div8"></div>
    </body>
</html>
#button {
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
}

#button:hover {
}
#div1 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 63px;
    top: 188px;
    left: 508px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#div2 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 63px;
    top: 229px;
    left: 508px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#div3 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 209px;
    left: 473px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#div4 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 209px;
    left: 571px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#div5 {
    height: 21px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 188px;
    left: 571px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#div6 {
    height: 21px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 188px;
    left: 473px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#div7 {
    height: 21px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 228px;
    left: 473px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#div8 {
    height: 21px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 228px;
    left: 571px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#div1:hover {
    top: 300px;
}
#div2:hover {

}
#div3:hover {

}
#div4:hover {

}
#div5:hover {

}
#div6:hover {

}
#div7:hover {

}
#div8:hover {

}
```

Comment: already in fiddle you've put the styles for hover and move the div by changing top, left etc. what exactly your doubt is, sorry i guess i din't got it.

Comment: but i want to move that BUTTON when you hover div1, i dont know how to set-up it, becouse i know only how to hover div1 when i move my cursor on div1, i want to move that button down when you move ur cursor on div1

Comment: Here's a css-only concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/6fsy8awj/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fsy8awj/2/)

You will have to do this with jQuery. In your 'transition' was a mistake, take a look at my changes.

**jQuery Code**

```
$( "#div1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#button').css('top','360px');
  },
//callback function being called after you leave the hover
function () {
     $('#button').css('top','200px');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it gives you some idea .

code:

js:

```
$( "#div1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#button').css('top','360px');

  }, 
         function () {
           $('#button').css('top','200px');
         }
);
```

fiddle for same : 
    http://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/6fsy8awj/1/

just add jquery.